# I cannot make infinite-scroll working on Onsen 2

Tags: onsen-ui, onsen-ui2

Based on the documentation on `Onsen2` ([this page](https://onsen.io/2/reference/ons-page.html)) `on-infinite-scroll` and `ng-infinite-scroll` should work, but I cannot make them work.

```
<ons-page modifier="material" ng-controller="PostListController" on-infinite-scroll="nextItems()" >
```

and

```
$scope.nextItems = function () {
    alert(1);
}
```

Is there any thing that I missed.

[codepen sample](http://codepen.io/RezaRahmati/pen/VaWMNM)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature was added in beta.8 so you need to update.
`on-infinite-scroll="nextItems"` should work for Vanilla JS and `ng-infinite-scroll="nextItems"` for AngularJS. Notice that I removed `()`.

You can also set `myPage.onInfiniteScroll` property to whatever function you want.

Example: http://codepen.io/frankdiox/pen/GZEyjR , http://codepen.io/IliaSky/pen/wGqRRz

**UPDATE:**
There was actually a bug in this feature that has been fixed already in beta.9.

Correct usage of infinite scroll in Vanilla JS is like this:

`<ons-page on-infinite-scroll="myHandler"> ... </ons-page>`

```
var myHandler = function(done) {
  console.log('do something');
  done();
}
```

In Angular 1 (same scope):

`<ons-page ng-infinite-scroll="myHandler"> ... </ons-page>`

```
$scope.myHandler = function(done) {
  console.log('do something');
  done();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Fran, Yes I am using beta8, I changed to "nextItems" and it's still not working, is there any way to debug and troubleshot the problem?

Comment: BTW the method only called the first time, I mean if you scroll to end you see the alert, then if you go up and scroll down again no message any more, should it be like this or it's a bug?

Comment: Update: I have downloaded the quickstart from the website and replaced the lib\onsenui with beta8, then I changed the page in the Material.html file as `    <ons-page modifier="material" ng-controller="TodoController as todo" ng-infinite-scroll="nextItems">` and I add the `nextItems` in the controller, and still it's not working, then I compared onsen.js and onsen-angualr.js files from cdn and my downloaded version and they are same too.

Comment: Update2: in Quickstart if I remove the template it works

Comment: Please take a look at this updated code pen: http://codepen.io/RezaRahmati/pen/yOXjJo

Comment: @RezaRahmati I have added a `done` function to the example. I think now it works as expected.

Comment: There is no difference, just call `done` function in `nextItems` as I did in my example.

Comment: Sorry, I think two different problems are mixed here, I mean the infinite scroll doesn't work at all when there is `template` no matter with done or without done http://codepen.io/RezaRahmati/pen/yOXjJo

Comment: http://codepen.io/frankdiox/pen/yOoBWd I can see the alert there everytime I scroll. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: In your first codepen I can see the alert, but in http://codepen.io/frankdiox/pen/yOoBWd I see NO alert (I tried in FF and Chrome)

Comment: Please see my prev comment :)

Comment: It actually worked just some times. Finally it stopped working after few times testing it again. There was a bug in the Angular bindings and has been fixed in master branch. You can test now this link: http://codepen.io/IliaSky/pen/wGqRRz

Comment: Yes, its working now, how can I make it work ? (since you are using this js https://www.dropbox.com/s/y4y1eha61hi69jp/onsenui.js?dl=1) is it Ok if I make a copy of this for my self?

Comment: It's better if you download the latest build: https://onsen.io/download.html#latest-build
I will update now the answer.